# The antibiotics tag is plural, thus should the probiotic tag be made plural as well?

Tags: discussion, tags

The antibiotics tag is plural, thus should the probiotic tag be made plural to make them consistent?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, make them consistent.  Change the [probiotic](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probiotic) tag to [probiotics](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probiotics) so it is consistent with [antibiotics](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antibiotics).

Answer (score 1):

I created a tag [probiotics](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probiotics), merged all of the current [probiotic](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probiotic) questions into it, and created a tag synonym to remap any future [probiotic](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probiotic) questions accordingly. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Sounds great!  Thanks Susan!